# Mod rewrite conflict

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't make redirect from http to https :'(
My actual .htaccess looks like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on    
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm adding next rows

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

But getting conflict with previous rows.

I put http://www.example.com/lents/johnson.html?type=1 to url.

And instead of getting same with https

I'm getting https://www.example.com/index.php?type=1

THANKS!

Comment: `/lents/johnson.html` the actual path to you file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your redirect rules above all the others so the redirect occurs before any of the URL rewriting happens:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```